# How to make vim substitute <script with <script type="..."></script>

Tags: vim, scripting

I created the following rule:

iabbrev <lt>script <script type="text/javascript"></script>

But during launch vim says:

Error detected while processing .vimrc:
line  290:
E474: Invalid argument

Pointing on that line. And I cannot workaround this, seems like the problem is in the left part, just like "script" is a reserved word.
Is there a way to escape it? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Filed this to vim-dev mailing list. Hope they will fix it in some future builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jörn Horstmann and @James Vega (from vim-dev mailing list) the problem may be solved: just add `<` to 'iskeyword' option, for example using

```
set iskeyword+=60 " 60==char2nr("<")
```

Note that 'iskeyword' option is used in lots of motions, so this may cause some negative side effects.

Comment: That's works, awesome! :)
Cool that there's an academic solution, bad that it's so deep and has side effects. However many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

consider using something like SnipMate: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

Then you have many macros already at hand, e.g.

```
snippet script
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       ${1}
   </script>${2}
```

in html.snippet

to use it, type in insert mode the following:   `script<TAB>` - the snipped will be inserted (without the `${n}` pieces) and the cursor will be where `${1}` was. Type your code, then press `<TAB>` again (still in insert mode), and the cursor will be after `</script>`.

There are MANY more snippets shipped with Snipmate for many languages. And it's really easy to create your own snippets as well.

Comment: Thanks for hinting! Will take a look on that as well.

Answer (score 2):

After several trys and reading of the documentation I don't think this mapping is possible. Citing from `:help abbreviations`:

> There are three types of abbreviations:
>
> full-id      The "full-id" type consists entirely of keyword characters (letters
>       and characters from 'iskeyword' option).  This is the most common
>       abbreviation.
>
> ```
> Examples: "foo", "g3", "-1"
> ```
>
> end-id   The "end-id" type ends in a keyword character, but all the other
>       characters are not keyword characters.
>
> ```
> Examples: "#i", "..f", "$/7"
> ```
>
> non-id   The "non-id" type ends in a non-keyword character, the other
>       characters may be of any type, excluding space and tab.  {this type
>       is not supported by Vi}
>
> ```
> Examples: "def#", "4/7$"
> ```
>
> Examples of strings that cannot be abbreviations: "a.b", "#def", "a b", "_$r"

So an abbreviation like `<script` seems to be impossible. You could of course define an abbreviation for `script` like this:

```
:inoreabbrev script <script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This way the opening bracket isn't part of the abbreviation <del>and so it is also not needed in the expansion</del>. The only problem is that you have to be careful when you want to write the text `script`. In that case you have to switch out of insert mode in the middle of the word or type `script<C-V><space>`.

Another useful trick to place the cursor in between the tags is a mapping like this, which jumps backwards to the previous opening bracket:

```
:inoreabbrev script <script type="text/javascript"></script><C-O>F<
```

Or, to place the tags on different lines with the cursor between them:

```
:inoreabbrev script <script type="text/javascript"><CR></script><C-O>O
```

Comment: Even if you thought it was not possible, what prevented you from adding `<` after you have wrote `script` (for example, using `<C-o>3Fs<`)?

Comment: Thanks, however it's weird that &lt;script cannot be an abbreviation. Everything works fine with &lt;script&gt; for instance.

Comment: @Denis Chmel While trying to find a workaround I noticed two things: 1. `<sc` also does not work. 2. Everything works in help window. Latter is very strange.

Comment: The allowed characters in abbreviations depend on the setting of 'iskeyword'. In help mode nearly all printable ascii characters are allowed as keywords. You can check the setting with `:set iskeyword?`.

Answer (score 0):

Just using two characters works in gVim (no idea why):

```
:iab <s <script>
```

typing `<s` then `space` gets `"<script>"`